# ipad, css orientation switching from 3 columns to 2 when in portrait

Tags: css, ipad, orientation

Sorry for posting this here, but having a bear of a time with an ipad issue when switching to portrait orientation in my website.

using a @media query to detect portrait, I want to switch from three columns to two.  The catch is, the div that is currently in the left column has dynamic content the expands its height and overlaps under the div that I have flipping from the right side into the left side.

I know that the newly located right div is burying the expanded content because I have set its "position:absolute".  Wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and has a quick a dirty fix.

Here are the two css elements in question that I want to populate the left side:

```
#main_wrapper #agenda_wrapper {
  width:23%;
  left: 5px;
  top: 2px;
}
#main_wrapper #summary_wrapper {
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 280px;
  width: 23%;
}
```

Here is the html structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="pageHeader">
  <div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="agenda_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div id="summary_wrapper"></div>
  </div>
 <footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to imagine a solution without your HTML structure, but I'll try.

This is what I think your are wanting:

1. You are switching stylesheets when in portrait view on an iPad
2. The `#agenda_wrapper` is over-laying the `#summary_wrapper`
3. `#agenda_wrapper` has a variable height based on the users content.
4. Assuming you want a CSS solution.

This is a good place for floats.  It doesn't make sense to absolutely position an element that needs to be variably positioned.

```
#agenda_wrapper,
#summary_wrapper 
{
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
}

#summary_wrapper {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip nate.  Did not work and it may have something to do with my html layout which I've added to the original question.  I'd like to make the whole solution work in css if possible as many of the users will be accessing the site via desktop.

Comment: can you try moving `div.main` down? Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/natedavisolds/FbXF8/

Comment: I did that as well as fiddled around with the .main class in the css and got it to work. Thanks!  Some conflicts with the efforts by the people making legacy (IE8) ui interactions work, but we are on our we on our way.